# Не отображается содержимое и сам элемент <script> во вкладке Elemets

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, npm

Изучая туториал по react   столкнулся с проблемой после подключения

```
npx create-react-app my-app
cd my-app 
npm start
```

В браузере на вкладке Elemets  пропал элемент  `<script>` с блоками кода. Вместо этого я вижу эту надпись (`npm run build` не помог):

> This HTML file is a template.   If you open it directly in the
>   browser, you will see an empty page.
>
> You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.   The
>   build step will place the bundled scripts into the  tag.
>
> To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.   To
>   create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.

И ничего  не  выводится  во вкладке  `console`

Comment: Не совсем понятно, что именно не так. Команда `npx create-react-app my-app` создает React-приложение, после этого нужно перейти в директорию проекта `cd my-app` и запустить скрипт `npm start`. Подозреваю, что Вы что-то упустили.

Comment: Это всё сделал,  после этого подключился к  localhost:3000.Там мой  отобразился index.htmlи.И переходя в инструменты у меня  в папке Elemets  посреди HTML  разметки появляется данное сообщение и     ничего не выводится в console.log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Create React App**](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html#create-react-app) — удобная среда для изучения React и лучший способ начать создание нового одностраничного приложения на React.

Инструмент настраивает среду для использования новейших возможностей JavaScript, оптимизирует приложение для продакшена и обеспечивает комфорт во время разработки. Вам понадобятся Node.js не ниже версии 8.10 и npm не ниже версии 5.6 на вашем компьютере. Для создания проекта выполните команды:

```
npx create-react-app my-app
cd my-app
npm start
```

Пошагово это выглядит следующим образом. Создаем React приложение (с помощью выполнения команды `npx create-react-app my-app`):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее идем в каталог созданного приложения (команда `cd my-app`) и смотрим, что лежит в папке (опциональный пункт, команда `ls`):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее запуск приложения (команда `npm start` или `yarn start` - кому как удобнее), приложение будет запущено на 3000 порту:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В браузере по-умолчанию должна открыться страница приложения (по адресу http://localhost:3000/):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В разметке будет всё по дефолту, смотрим следующее изображение:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Этот HTML-файл, который отображается на странице в браузере - является шаблоном (лежит в папке `public` вашего проекта и называется `index.html`). Вы можете добавить в этот файл веб-шрифты, метатеги или аналитику. Всё, что касается React - попадает в тэг с идентификатором `root`. В каталоге `src` лежит компонент `App.js` из которого рендерится содержимое в `div` с айдишником `root`. Всё просто.

Comment: я всё понял,короче  как всегда..не доглядел.Спасибо вам.

Comment: @ZdraviSmisl да не за что. Когда изучаешь что-то новое - легко упустить из виду какую-нибудь мелочь.